# Completely strip any hidden formatting when pasting into TinyMCE

Tags: filters, tinymce, formatting

In WordPress v4+, I want to remove all hidden formatting when users paste content into TinyMCE visual editor.

The *Paste as Text* button works when users insert text from Microsoft Word but doesn't do its job with other applications like Pages for OSX.

You can use the following to filter away all formatting for Word (thanks [Till Kruss](http://wordpress.org/plugins/paste-as-plain-text/)):

```
class PasteAsPlainText {

    function __construct() {

        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'init' ) );

    }

    function init() {

        add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', array( $this, 'forcePasteAsPlainText' ) );
        add_filter( 'teeny_mce_before_init', array( $this, 'forcePasteAsPlainText' ) );
        add_filter( 'teeny_mce_plugins', array( $this, 'loadPasteInTeeny' ) );
        add_filter( 'mce_buttons_2', array( $this, 'removePasteAsPlainTextButton' ) );

    }

    function forcePasteAsPlainText( $mceInit ) {

        global $tinymce_version;

        if ( $tinymce_version[0] < 4 ) {
            $mceInit[ 'paste_text_sticky' ] = true;
            $mceInit[ 'paste_text_sticky_default' ] = true;
        } else {
            $mceInit[ 'paste_as_text' ] = true;
        }

        return $mceInit;
    }

    function loadPasteInTeeny( $plugins ) {

        return array_merge( $plugins, (array) 'paste' );

    }

    function removePasteAsPlainTextButton( $buttons ) {

        if( ( $key = array_search( 'pastetext', $buttons ) ) !== false ) {
            unset( $buttons[ $key ] );
        }

        return $buttons;

    }

}

new PasteAsPlainText();
```

And then you can hide the *Paste as Text* button (to disallow users from unticking it) by selecting which buttons you want to show:

```
function formatTinyMCE( $in ) {
    $in['toolbar1'] = 'bold,custom_em,blockquote,aligncenter,link,unlink,spellchecker,undo,removeformat';
    return $in; 
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'formatTinyMCE' );
```

Now that we have got Word out of the way (finally), how do we completely strip all hidden formatting pasted into TinyMCE?

**UPDATE**: One approach *could* be to find an init option like [paste_word_valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3Apaste_word_valid_elements) and have an empty list of valid tags.

Comment: I got to the point where I was having clients paste into notepad/textedit first, hope you find a better solution.

Comment: @AndrewBartel Absolutely, this has by far been our biggest obstacle. I believe we struggled with Word for a full year until we found a complete solution, just to see that the issue is still present with other apps.

Comment: Have you looked at the default [TinyMCE Plugins on GitHub](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/bedc3541d5c732c9105bd1e4ea22ce16937049aa/js/tinymce/plugins/paste/classes/Plugin.js#L25) such as [there are quite some examples for `paste`](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/tree/bedc3541d5c732c9105bd1e4ea22ce16937049aa/js/tinymce/plugins/paste/classes).

Comment: I think we need something along the lines of the paste_word_valid_elements init option but for generic paste events.

Comment: What formatting is getting through? I tried pasting various bold/underline/font/table/list stuff using TextEdit (and a dubious copy of Pages) and it was stripped ok.

Comment: @bonger Can you please confirm which browser you are using and also what code you have added to filter the paste. Are you using the code that I have posted in my question?

Comment: Yes just using the exact same code, in Safari. (Am using a Hackintosh in VirtualBox).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite understand what you need but I think that you trying to insert text as plain text from anywhere: Browser, M$ Word, Pages.

For this purpose you can use [Advanced TinyMCE Configuration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-tinymce-configuration/) plugin. After download and activating this plugin requires manual configuration. This solution better than code you suggested in question section above).

```
Option name                  Value
paste_strip_class_attributes all
paste_remove_spans           true
paste_remove_styles          true
paste_as_text                true
paste_text_sticky            true
block_formats                Paragraph=p;Header 2=h2;...
```

All of these parts (parameters) of config may be founded on [Tiny MCE documentation pages](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration).

1. `paste_strip_class_attributes` — old attribute from 3.?.? version
   for removing all tags attributes like `href`, `alt`, `class`,
   `onError`,..
2. `paste_remove_spans` — also from 3.?.? version. Enables you to
   remove all span (inline?) elements while pasting.
3. `paste_remove_styles` — If true, removes all style information when
   pasting, regardless of browser type. Pasting from Word 2000 will
   cause tinyMCE to error.
4. `paste_as_text` — This option enables you to set the default state
   of the "paste as text" edit menu option. It's disabled by default
   but can be forced on by default.
5. `paste_text_sticky` — Keeps Paste Text feature active until user
   deselects the Paste as Text button.
6. `block_formats` — additional configuration for my site :)

This config working fine on my sites and I always insert text in TinyMCE like a plain text.

Also helpfull plugin for TinyMCE tuning [TinyMCE Advanced](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/).